# How to replace an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, reference

Say I have some deeply nested array structure and a reference to an object inside:

```
strings = ["1", "2", " 3"]
nested = [[strings] * 10] * 10
reference = nested[0][0][0]
```

How do I replace the object `reference` points to with eg. `"4"`? I need somthing generic that works with arbitrary objects, not `String#gsub!` and friends. Something like `Object#replace(other_obj)`.

Comment: `nested[0][0][0] = "4"`? You're going to have to be more clear about what your "arbitrary objects" are, or else the answer is: Assignment. You use *assignment* to replace one object with another.

Comment: the other object is some object, not necessarily a String!

Comment: You won't be able to replace all objects in Ruby. For example you won't be able to replace a literal number. Moreover, you can't replace one object to become a different object, if that's something you were also interested in doing.

Comment: yes that's what I was asking about. Is it possible?

Comment: What you can do is replace the internal state of **some** Ruby objects. See for example [`String#replace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-replace). Several other objects also have a `replace` method, for example arrays and hashes.
You could implement a `replace` method on your own objects, if you can modify their internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, we don't have (explicit) pointers in Ruby, we have (implicit) references but you can't dereference them to mess with what they contain. Instead, you need to do something like:

```
inner nested[0][0]
inner[0] = '4'
```

so that you can work with a reference to the element you want to replace rather than the element itself.

Of course, with the structure in your question, that `inner[0] = '4'` will replace the first element of `strings` (and thus every element of `nested` since it is just a pile of references to the same array that `strings` references.

Sorry about how overloaded the term *reference* is here. It is a horrible abuse of English but English itself is an abuse of English :)